# how is the performance of pyramix

Tags: daw

Yesterday i happened to see the pyramix DAW.I am a Nuendo user and have got a basic experience working in protools.How is the performance of this software.Is it a widely used software?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is widely used, At least not in the areas where I work. I live and work in Denmark, in the film industry, and here approximately 100 % of the studios use Protools. I have traded Protools sessions with Germany, Sweden, Norway, Macedonia and USA, and I have never heard any requests for other formats.

I have worked on Pyramix once, in a foley studio in Paris. I recorded foley with a french foley artist. It worked just fine, it was quick and robust, just as Protools is. It had two interesting features:

1. the Vcube, which is a video soft/hardware solution for Pyramix. It has some very cool features. It can work with multiple video tracks, so you can make a small movie window in the corner of the picture, which is ahead of the main picture. This way the foley artist can be more prepared and more in sync, and the foley session runs smoother. You can change the setup at any time, since it is calculated in real time, which makes the system very flexible. I have tried doing the same in Protools, but you will have to render the video file in Quicktime Pro, so you can't change it on the fly, if you need the small picture to be in a different corner, or if you need a different delay between the pictures.

[image]
<sub>(source: [lydtilfilm.dk](http://lydtilfilm.dk/vcube.jpg))</sub>

2. When you finish a recording, a naming window pops up automatically, so you can name the region instead of having to double click the region first. This saves a little time.

Apart from that, I can't see any reason to get a Pyramix system. On Protools you can trade sessions directly with most other studios, without losing automation or plugins (if you have agreed in advance on which plugins to use!). Pyramix can read and write Protools sessions, but it is an older version and not without difficulties.

I'm afraid I can't say anything about Nuendo, as I am not a Nuendo user.

Comment: Thanx for the comments.Compared to protools( i haven't tried that much) i think Nuendo is more user friendly.As far as know the routing in pro-tools is very similar to a mixer unlike Nuendo.